# Can I get value of actual write capacity of DynamoDB or DynamoDB2 table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto, throughput

Suppose I access an existing DynamoDB

```
import boto
conn = boto.connect_dynamodb(...)
table = conn.get_table(tableName)
```

or a DynamoDB2

```
import boto
from boto.dynamodb2.layer1 import DynamoDBConnection
from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table
conn = DynamoDBConnection(...)
table = Table(tableName, connection=conn)
```

table. I want to know how much data was written to it right before I accessed it. So I don't want the provisioned write throughput value but the actual throughput. How can I get this info?

Comment: Not familiar with boto, but you would likely need to look at cloudwatch metrics associated with the table.

Comment: Can I get the cloudwatch metrics values programmatically?

Comment: Yes. Of course.  here is the link to the API documentation - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html  Here is boto documentation as well - http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cloudwatch_tut.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
import boto.ec2.cloudwatch
import datetime

end = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
start = end - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
c = boto.ec2.cloudwatch.connect_to_region('us-east-1')
data = c.get_metric_statistics(period=60, start_time=start, end_time=end,   
         metric_name='ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits', namespace='AWS/DynamoDB',
         statistics=['Sum'],dimensions={'TableName': 'mytable'})
```

This should a list of data points.  You should average all of the sums in the list and then divide that number by 300, the period.

Comment: Tried it for a few of my tables and always got an empty array back for `data`.

Comment: Sorry, had the metric_name wrong.  I just corrected that.

Comment: Tried this one too. Same result

Comment: I just tried the above again and it worked for me.  Are you passing the correct table name?  Are you connecting to the correct region?

Comment: Actually, try changing the time range by increasing the ``minutes`` in the timedelta call or reducing the ``period`` to a smaller value (e.g. 60).

Comment: OK it worked after I fiddled with the numbers a bit.