# CloudWatch produces dated info for DynamoDB table

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

This is a follow-up to an [**earlier**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24293803/can-i-get-value-of-actual-write-capacity-of-dynamodb-or-dynamodb2-table) question

I am running a modified version of the code that was proposed in the solution to that question:

```
import os
import boto
import boto.ec2.cloudwatch
import datetime

aws_key = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', None)
aws_secret = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', None)

end = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
start = end - datetime.timedelta(minutes=400)
tName = 'Name-of-my-table'
stats = ['Average', 'Sum', 'SampleCount', 'Maximum', 'Minimum']
c = boto.ec2.cloudwatch.connect_to_region('us-east-1',aws_access_key_id=aws_key,aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret)
data = c.get_metric_statistics(period=60, start_time=start, end_time=end,   
     metric_name='ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits', namespace='AWS/DynamoDB',
     statistics=stats,dimensions={'TableName': tName})
data2 = {}         
for d in data:
    data2[d['Timestamp']] = str(d)

ordered_keys = sorted(data2.keys())
for k in ordered_keys:
    print "%s" % k
```

What I expect is a list of timestamps corresponding to the cloudwatch datapoints. I do get that but the timestamps are quite dated, i.e. they correspond to about 6 hours before the time I actually ran the code. Is my info for table stats incorrect or is something else wrong? Why am I getting dated info?

Answer (score 0):

humm, your code seems correct. I copied and run your code against my table and I can get the latest metrics. The only thing I changed is table_name and region.

I did notice that the timestamp returned in the result is in GMT. so it is 7 hours later compared to my local time (PST). Also it seems CloudWatch is doing sampling every 5 minuntes. so you should expect only a 5 min delay.